# How can I insert multiple values in a tkinter listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I insert multiple values in a tkinter listbox column?
Normally there is only one value in each column, but is there a way to insert multiple values in to one column.

For Example:

column1

A,B

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontally oriented listbox using Python and Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082723/horizontally-oriented-listbox-using-python-and-tkinter)

Comment: no , but thx for a reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. Just pass them all to the `insert` method:

```
the_listbox.insert("end", "one", "two", "three", "four")
```

Comment: Hey it works, but they are shown underneath each other. How can I manage them to be next to each other on the right side.

Comment: @Dan: yes, the listbox only supports a single column, and you said you wanted them in the same column. Asking how to display multiple columns in a listbox is a completely different question.

Comment: ok, do you knnow how to do it?